# 'NoneType' object has no attribute error in Binary Tree implementation in python

Tags: python, binary-tree, non-type

I wrote the following code to simply implement a binary tree in python. I get "**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'**" when I am calling the "**find_Node**" method. I know what this error is, but I cannot find out why it just appears when I call "**find_Node**" method. Any clue would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

class BinaryTree:

    class Node:

        def __init__(self,data,left=None,right=None):
            self.data=data
            self.left=left
            self.right=right

        def get_RightChild(self):
            return self.right

        def get_LeftChilld(self):
            return self.left

        def get_Nodedata(self):
            return self.data

        def set_NodeData(self,data):
            self.data=data

    def __init__(self,rootdata):
        self.root=self.Node(rootdata)
        self.size=1

    def get_Root(self):
        return self.root

    def get_Size(self):
        return self.size


    def insert_LeftNode(self,data,root):
        if root.left==None:
            root.left=self.Node(data)
        else:
            self.insert_LeftNode(data,root.left)
        self.size+=1

    def insert_RightNode(self,data,root):
        if root.right==None:
            root.right=self.Node(data)
        else:
            self.insert_RightNode(data,root.right)
        self.size+=1

    #needs revision - does not work properly
    def find_Node(self,data,root):
        if root.data == data:
            return 1
        self.find_Node(data,root.right)
        self.find_Node(data,root.left)
        return 0

    def preorder_Traverse(self,root):
        if root != None:
            print root.data,
            self.preorder_Traverse(root.left)
            self.preorder_Traverse(root.right)

    def inorder_Traverse(self,root):
        if root!=None:
            self.inorder_Traverse(root.left)
            print root.data,
            self.inorder_Traverse(root.right)

    def postorder_Traverse(self,root):
        if root!=None:
            self.postorder_Traverse(root.left)
            self.postorder_Traverse(root.right)
            print root.data,


if __name__=="__main__":
    mybinary=BinaryTree(314)
    mybinary.insert_LeftNode(6,mybinary.get_Root())
    mybinary.insert_RightNode(7,mybinary.get_Root())
    mybinary.insert_LeftNode(2,mybinary.root.left)
    mybinary.insert_RightNode(4,mybinary.root.left)

    mybinary.inorder_Traverse(mybinary.get_Root())

    print 

    if mybinary.find_Node(7,mybinary.get_Root()): 
        print "found"
    else: 
        print "Not Found!"
```

Comment: You should check if `root` is `None` when you are doing recursive calls for `find_Node`, also the logic for `find_Node` is wrong.

Comment: I did but it still does not work. Besides, in main, it is obvious that root is not None.

Answer (score 0):

Check is `root` is `None`, also `root.left` or `root.right` could be `None`, change your `find_Node` method to the code below

```
def find_Node(self,data,root):
    if(root is None):
        return 0
    if root.data == data:
        return 1
    return self.find_Node(data,root.right) or self.find_Node(data,root.left)
```